# Google API YouTube Sample - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: .net, json, git, youtube

I cloned Youtube API Samples from GitHub:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples.git

and created the following OAuth 2 Client ID:

[image]

I downloaded the JSON and dropped it into `client-secrets.json`.

However, when I execute the sample code, I get the following:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:55015/authorize/, does not 
match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

I'm really confused, because I didn't specify that URI as my "Redirect URI".  I don't even know where it is coming from ... it looks like some random port was selected.

Anyone seen this before or have any insight?

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your redirect uri in the code for the authorization process?

For example, in [api-samples/php/my_uploads.php](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/my_uploads.php):

```
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
```

try changing `$redirect` to `https://yourredirecturi.com/callback`